# Centering with margin: 0 auto; vs. justify-content and flexbox

Tags: css, margin, text-justify

Doing some html horizontal center stuff, I just realized that I could use both things to center a box element into its parent, so my question is which of those 2 are better (in terms of performance, usability, etc).

Comment: How would one even compare the two by those metrics (performance and usability)? What do they even *mean* in this context?

Comment: with usability I wanted to ask what is the most common way you use to center an element into its parent. About performance I wanted to know if there were loading differences when the DOM was rendering the layout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `div` or `p` it's better to use `margin: 0px auto;` for containers or main page,
But if you need two or more children to be centered, it's better to set parent to `text-align:center` and the children to `display: inline-block`.

Answer (score 3):

Because of the way margins are handled in flex, these do the same job.

But as a general practice, when you have more div's, using flex would do the job more accurately and will provide you choice for distributing the space equally". 
When you have few div' , you can go with `margin:auto` .
Remember flexbox provides us the choice for redistributing the space.